# handling special characters in textboxes and using splitters

Tags: c#, .net-4.6.1

What is a good option when using strings and special characters and splitters?

for example

```
string name = "test, test";
string result = name + @"test, test";
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

lets say i want this string to split and into the list for each item.
in this case 'name is an item' and 'test, test' is an item

so i can do something like this:

```
String.split(list.ToArray(), ',');
```

i will use the comma as the seperator but both items already contains them aswell.

the result should be:

> 0 test, test
>   1 test, test

but since it splits on the comma, the result will be

> 0 test
>   1 test
>   2 test
>   3 test

to prevent this i can to something like

```
if(name.Contains(","))
{
    name = name.Replace(",","comma");
}
```

and then convert back.
But i don't like this code it's kinda spaghetti.
what i can do instea is make a class translationadapter and 2 methods converter and deconverter

but how do you check for those special characters or what would you suggest in such situation like this.
Cause i have got situations like this but with multiple special character like , and #. but i don't want to restrict the textbox.

Comment: (1) The best option is to not concatenate the strings in the first place. (2) How are you adding the strings to the list?

Comment: Why do you want to split here ? The result should be "0 test test 1 test, test" your first item in the list is your name, you second is the new string. You just have to add them to the list without joining them. In the way you present your problem you don't need split because you have separate strings from the begining.

Comment: It depends where your data is coming from. If you can choose not to concatenate them together in the first place (put them straight into a list) then that's going to be better. If you're expecting to handle character-seperated data typed in by a user, you may just have to be strict about what separators you accept. This is a critical problem with CSV formats in and of themselves.

Comment: Better off using collection data structures than concatenating and then slicing.

Comment: String doesn't have such a split method. Your result is "test, testtest, test", so what makes "test, test" an item and "test, test" another item? What is the logic here? Why not simply add them to your list as items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways to go about it.

### Use a different delimiter

It's not mandatory to use the `,` delimiter when joining or splitting strings. That's why some csv files use the `;` character: to avoid the comma issue.

### String.Replace() as you did already

Replace in the individual strings all the characters you want to remain.

### Use a regular expression to split

If you know that your strings have the same pattern like `\d\stest,\stest` then you can use the [Regex.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=netframework-4.8) function that uses regular expressions to split the string.

Comment: thx for the answer but that's exactly the problem, the splitting happens inside the cms system which I can't access its backend code. they use , as its delimiter so i was trying to find kinda translation adapter. I could use regex to find special characters